# Custom site template not including all titles

Tags: 2013, web-part, site-template, web-template

I have a custom site template, that I made by first creating a site, a couple of doc libraries and custom lists, and put some webparts on the "frontpage" that shows certain views in these doc libs. The thing is, when I save site as template and create a new one, the custom title that I gave the webparts aren't showing up, and instead I'm getting the default title of the doc library.

I have a content editor webpart on the same page, which DOES save the custom title - but not the custom description?

I've tried everything, I unpacked the wsp as a cab, tried finding all references and titles for the relevant webparts but nothing seems to work - and I can't even find a single reference to the content editor webpart to see how that one remembers the custom title.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: Did you choose the option, 'Include Content' when saving the site template?

Comment: Yes I did. It's weird that it only saves the custom title of SOME webparts, like the CEWP and not the Doc Library webparts

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to the problem per say, but since it seems like a bug, and I can't find anywhere in the packaged template WSP to change it, I decided on changing the webpart titles manually in my site creation code, after the fact.

For anyone interested, it's something like this:

```
using(ClientContex ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl){
    File webPartPage = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(webPartPageUrl);
    LimitedWebPartManager wpm = webPartPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    ctx.load(wpm.WebParts,
        owpm => owpm.Include(w=>w.WebPart));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    WebPartDefinion webPart = wpm.WebParts.FirstOrDefault(w=>w.WebPart.Title == "WebPartTitle");
    webPart.WebPart.Title = "New Title";
    webPart.SaveWebPartChanges();
    ctx.Web.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```